# Why is the transforms input pointing to a wrong dataset when replacing path with RID?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

In my Code Repository I have updated the Input to use a new dataset.
[image]

When I replace the filename with the RID,

[image]

it changes back to the former Input Dataset. How can I include a new dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the correct dataset in the Input-statement (before “Replace paths with RIDs”), delete the file `transforms-shrinkwrap.yml`.
This file is hidden, so you want to “Show hidden files and folders”

[image]

Afterwards trigger a new build (The CI Checks could take longer this time as the file has to be recreated).
After the build you should be able to “Replace paths with RIDs” and still see the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your transformation python / py file is in the correct folder too. else the build will prompt this error..